# captcha validating post in form

Tags: php, captcha

I just want to know what should i put more in order to guess if captcha is wrong or not in my $_POST (the captcha image works fine in my form) so my question is how to put the errors if the user input a wrong captcha in my captcha image?

```
if ($_POST['captcha'] !== $_POST['real']) {
    $errors[] = 'You're wrong';
}
```

Here is my captcha code

```
session_start();

function random($length) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789";
    $str = "";
    $size = strlen($chars);
    for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
        $str .=$chars [rand (0, $size-1)];
    }

    return $str;
}

$cap = random(7);
$_SESSION['real'] = $cap;

$image = imagecreate(100, 20);
$background = imagecolorallocate ($image, 0,0,0);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255,255,255);

imagestring($image, 5,5,1,$cap,$foreground);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg") ;
imagejpeg ($image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is very clear.  Easy to read for humans.  Also easy to read for bots.   I tested your code and put the image through a simple online OCR (http://www.i2ocr.com/ ) and it came back with the test perfectly.

Try it yourself.

I would consider using an existing captcha library. Such as the Google Captcha options.  I like the no captcha recaptcha ( http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html )

--- Edit to answer this case.

In your captcha processing file

```
session_start();
$errors[]=array();
if ($_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['real']) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry.  Incorrect Response.  Please Try Again';
}

if(count($errors)>0){
//show user the errors
  print_r($errors);  //You should make this pretty
//probably go back to the login form
echo'<a href="loginform.php">Go Back and Try Again</a>';
//stop processing
exit();
)

//if we got here then the posted captcha matche the 'real' session variable.

echo'Yay!  You got it right!';
```

Comment: i just want to make one for me without using other internet captcha and i just want to validate the captcha :(

Comment: @RoyLesterSantos  added an edit that should help you resolve the matching of the captcha posted to the session variable 'real'